# having error while using 'Series' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: python, pandas

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

refer this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLm32.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLm32.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `.iloc` is used for `Series` instead of `.ix`.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions); flag them for closing instead.